# It it possible to use Managed Identities to access to a queue or topic similar to what I can do with SAS?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Based on the following article I understand that I can create SAS Policies to have a secured access to an specific service bus queue or topic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas#shared-access-authorization-policies

It is important to note that with SAS Polity I can authorize an application to have access to an specific queue but not to the rest of of Service Bus entities.

Can I do the same with Managed Identities?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to scope to an individual entity within a namespace. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity#resource-scope.